# Aristotle and taste preferences of animals

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, history-of-philosophy, aristotle

We probably can assume that Aristotle knew at least *some* “sensitive” (conscious) animals which have *very* different preferences in taste than humans. For example vultures (they occur in Greece), which like carrion – something that has a repellent smell and taste for humans.

Did he ever make any attempt to incorporate this fact in his philosophy of mind and perception? To square this with his perceptual realism (= sensible qualities are mind-independent qualities of objects)?

What I mean is, if Aristotle thought that vultures experience the same smell and taste of carrion as humans – yet they *like* it. Or if they experience a different smell and taste.

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think it poses a problem for Aristotle. In that animals can perceive what they find tasty without that affecting what is good or well-ordered in human perception (unless you think we're vultures too?)

Comment: Humans can acquire a taste for carrion. (Animals' eating is not a rational activity as humans' eating is.)